# How to set liferay portletURL/actionURL to POST method

Tags: http, liferay, liferay-6

I have these 2 similar function in my jsp file.

```
PortletURL deleteURL = renderResponse.createActionURL();
deleteURL.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME, "deleteUser");
deleteURL.setParameter("redirectURL", redirectURL.toString());
```

and

```
<portlet:actionURL name="deleteUser" var="deleteURL">
<portlet:param name="resourcePrimKey" value="<%=userid%>" />
<portlet:param name="redirectURL" value="<%=userPage.toString()  %>" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

They are however using GET method and I am trying to find a way to use POST instead. Where/how may I change to POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These URLs are neither using GET nor POST, they are just URLs. In order to use them, you will have to do something with them, e.g. use them in a `<form>` or `<a>` element like this:

In addition to your code from the question, you'll have something like this:

GET:

```
 <a href="<%=deleteURL%>">click me</a>
```

POST:

```
 <form action="<%=deleteURL%>" method="POST">
   <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: Actually currently my codes are using <a>. I was thinking that there was a function or portlet:something to set them. Thanks anyways

Comment: `<a>` will always use GET (unless you're tricking it with fancy javascript)